# Create dictionary inside mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big problem.

I'm new in sql but i did nice things for a project, but i have an issue:

In a PHP page there are 2 fields  DATE(  ) and NOTE(  ) and i need that to each DATA is associate a NOTE.

When the user insert new values in these fields, in the database must be added

```
DATE1(...) --> NOTE1(...)
DATE2(...) --> NOTE2(...)
DATE3(...) --> NOTE3(...)
etc.
```

So when i call DATE1 from PHP, it shows DATE1(..) and NOTE1(...).

How can i store this kind of Dictionary ( i used DIC in python ) in my DB?

I thought to create for each DATE and NOTE a column called DATE1 -- NOTE1, but is an orrible, heavy and hard solution.

All ideas are good accepted.
Thank you for your time

Comment: You could store it as a json field? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: You create a table for the extra data which has a date field. Note field and a field to link the id for the main data in your other table. This is called a one to many relationship. Similar to this. http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/